# Ramanujan results for middle school?

Tags: middle-school

Pls I wonder what Ramanujan's results could be explained to middle school level audience, ie without using integral etc that is up to university curriculum?

For example [Ramanujan's infinite radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Ramanujan%27s_infinite_radicals) could be explained easily

$$ 3=\sqrt {1+2{\sqrt {1+3{\sqrt {1+\cdots }}}}}$$

Comment: Why Ramanujan specifically?

Comment: just his results have many infinite forms, which sound fun! @ChrisCunningham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [Rogers–Ramanujan identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_identities):

- The number of partitions of $n$ in which adjacent parts are at least 2 apart is the same as the number of partitions of $n$ in which each part ends with 1,4,6,9.
- The number of partitions of $n$ *without 1* in which adjacent parts are at least 2 apart is the same as the number of partitions of $n$ in which each part ends with 2,3,7,8.

For example, taking $n=10$:

- Partitions in which adjacent parts are at least 2 apart:
  $$
  10 = 10 = 9 + 1 = 8 + 2 = 7 + 3 = 6 + 4 = 6 + 3 + 1
  $$
- Partitions in which each part ends with 1,4,6,9:
  $$
  10 = 9 + 1 = 6 + 4 = 6 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4 + 4 + 1 + 1 = 4 + 6\times 1 = 10 \times 1
  $$
- Partitions without 1 in which adjacent parts are at least 2 apart:
  $$
  10 = 10 = 8 + 2 = 7 + 3 = 6 + 4
  $$
- Partitions in which each part ends with 2,3,5,8:
  $$
  10 = 8 + 2 = 7 + 3 = 3 + 3 + 2 + 2 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2
  $$